# Has anyone had issues with _POST data being blocked by a Godaddy web hosting server?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am using a form processor called JotForm. They allow $_POST data to be sent to the URL of your choosing when the form is submitted. For  some unknown reason I get an empty array when I try to print all POST data **BUT ONLY** when I host the page on a godaddy. I've hosted it at localhost and had no issues. I used some guy named [Henry's "POST Testing Page"](https://www.posttestserver.com/) and all of the data was there.

The form URL: https://form.jotform.co/71083125989868

GoDaddy Hosted POST Reciever: cyoacharters.com/post_test.php

The code in my POST receiver:

```
<?php print_r ($_POST); ?>
```

Data received by Henry's data tester:

```html
Time: Wed, 19 Apr 17 06:05:28 -0700
Source ip: 199.77.132.36

Headers (Some may be inserted by server)
REQUEST_URI = /post.php
QUERY_STRING = 
REQUEST_METHOD = POST
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = CGI/1.1
REMOTE_PORT = 52455
REMOTE_ADDR = 199.77.132.36
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = en-US,en;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = gzip, deflate, br
HTTP_REFERER = https://submit.jotform.co/submit/71083125989868/
HTTP_ACCEPT = text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
CONTENT_TYPE = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
HTTP_USER_AGENT = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS = 1
HTTP_ORIGIN = https://submit.jotform.co
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL = max-age=0
CONTENT_LENGTH = 110
HTTP_CONNECTION = close
HTTP_HOST = posttestserver.com
SSL_TLS_SNI = posttestserver.com
HTTPS = on
UNIQUE_ID = WPdgmEBaMGUAAFt7ZmUAAAAD
REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT = 1492607128.5826
REQUEST_TIME = 1492607128

Post Params:
key: 'submission_id' value: '3684163276328228389'
key: 'formID' value: '71083125989868'
key: 'ip' value: '199.77.132.36'
key: 'firstname' value: 'John'
key: 'lastname' value: 'Doe'
key: 'rgb' value: 'Green'
Empty post body.

Upload contains PUT data:
submission_id=3684163276328228389&formID=71083125989868&ip=199.77.132.36&firstname=John&lastname=Doe&rgb=Green
```

I was thinking that maybe something is disabled in my php settings on the godaddy website, if you think that may be the case, here is the php info: cyoacharters.com/phpinfo.php

At this point, I'm totally stuck. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try this  $jsonData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData, true)
print_r($phpArray,true);

Comment: @Avihaym - I think you mean: `print_r($phpArray,true);` (you're missing `y` in Array).

Comment: Your php.ini looks fine. (variables_order specifies what global variables you can use, so you have GPCS which means GET, POST, COOKIE and SESSION). I'd recommend also to increase max_input_vars.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the post data from the below code as well. It returns the raw data if the form is not urlencoded

```
file_get_contents('php://input)
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha! The problem was actually with the form service, JotForm. Everything is working the way it should. Thank you for your time.